# Code works in Jupyter but error out in Spyder

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder

Here is a simple code I am trying to run on Jupyter and then on Spyder on Mac for Python 2.7

Code on Jupyter Lab (Works Fine)

> ```
> print(*range(1, int(input())+1), sep='')
>
> 6
> 123456
> ```

Same code on Spyder errors out

```
>   print(*range(1, int(input())+1), sep='')
>           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please suggest if may be missing something here?

Comment: add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your script and try again.

Comment: Still the same.. no luck

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that you are running Python 2.7 in Spyder, but Python 3.* in Jupyter?  The syntax error you show is typical of Python 2.7 since tuple unpacking was introduced in 3.

You can test by using:

```
import sys
v = sys.version_info
print(v.major, v.minor)
```

Comment: Thanks for checking, I only have 2.7 installed on my machine. And both the IDE's are running on 2.7